# Javascript - split an array into complex section list with titles

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to convert `fields` array into a section list format. The example of an expected output can be found in the reproduction below.

Basically, the `fieldName` should be mapped with the corresponding value in `values` object. I'm currently stuck with it and cannot figure out of how to concat these two sources of data - `values` and `fields`.

How can this be done? Thank you in advance?

Reproduction example with expected output:

```js
const values = {
  Num: "Num_Value",
  Language: "English",
  
  CustomerName: "Customer name",
  Email: "email@gmail.com",
  
  RefNum: "0102",
  Code: "code",
  
  Country: "ES",
  Address: "Addr",
}

const fields = [
  {
    firstStep: [{ fieldName: 'Num' }, { fieldName: 'Language' }],
  },
  {
    secondStep: [{ fieldName: 'CustomerName' }, { fieldName: 'Email' }],
  },
  {
    thirdStep: [{ fieldName: 'RefNum' }, { fieldName: 'Code' }],
  },
  {
    fourthStep: [{ fieldName: 'Country' }, { fieldName: 'Address' }],
  }
];

const res = fields.reduce((item, acc) => {

  // How to map fields with values and get the expected result? 
  console.log(Object.entries(item), 'item');
  
  return acc;
}, []);


console.log(res, 'res');


// Expected result
const result = [
  {
    title: "firstStep",
    data: [{ fieldName: "Num", value: "Num_Value"}, { fieldName: "Language", value: "English"}]
  },
  {
    title: "secondStep",
    data: [{ fieldName: "CustomerName", value: "Customer name"}, { fieldName: "Email", value: "email@gmail.com"}]
  },
  {
    title: "thirdStep",
    data: [{ fieldName: "RefNum", value: "0102"}, { fieldName: "Code", value: "code"}]
  },
  {
    title: "fourthStep",
    data: [{ fieldName: "Country", value: "ES"}, { fieldName: "Address", value: "Addr"}]
  }
];
```

Comment: `values` is just a head: how would anyone, including code, ever know that `CustomerName` and `email` belong together but not `CustomerName` and `Addr` or even `CustomerName` and `Num`?

Comment: `fields` array specifies the fields, which stand together

Comment: So then just use a double map? First turn `fields` into something that has uniform naming, e.g. `newdata = Object.entries(fields).map(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `key-value` pairs of each element, and use `.map` to fill out the `values`:

```js
const values = {
  Num: "Num_Value",
  Language: "English",
  
  CustomerName: "Customer name",
  Email: "email@gmail.com",
  
  RefNum: "0102",
  Code: "code",
  
  Country: "ES",
  Address: "Addr",
}

const fields = [
  {
    firstStep: [{ fieldName: 'Num' }, { fieldName: 'Language' }],
  },
  {
    secondStep: [{ fieldName: 'CustomerName' }, { fieldName: 'Email' }],
  },
  {
    thirdStep: [{ fieldName: 'RefNum' }, { fieldName: 'Code' }],
  },
  {
    fourthStep: [{ fieldName: 'Country' }, { fieldName: 'Address' }],
  }
];

const res = fields.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const [title] = Object.keys(item);
  const [fieldElements] = Object.values(item);
  const data = fieldElements.map(e => ({...e, value: values[e.fieldName] }));
  acc.push({ title, data });
  return acc;
}, []);


console.log(res);
```